# Are docker images and containers visible to everyone on the server?

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to make a docker image for one of my simulators. But is the docker image on the server shared by all users?

I just tried the `docker images` command, and the results showed that there are several images:

```
ubuntu                latest              9873176a8ff5        2 months ago        72.7MB
hello-world           latest              d1165f221234        6 months ago        13.3kB
mpx_evaluation        latest              ae93b04419ab        13 months ago       686MB
ubuntu                16.04               77be327e4b63        18 months ago       124MB
e9patch/e9patchdemo   latest              e73fd4d392d8        19 months ago       696MB
neo4j                 latest              7e40ffda399a        2 years ago         362MB
```

Are these images used by others? I don’t want everyone to be able to see the image I made. Is there any way? Why is the images public to everyone? What if someone deletes my image by mistake?

The model of the server I am using is: `Linux server81 4.15.0-142-generic #146~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 09:27:15 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Many people use this server.

Comment: There is only one Docker installation on a server.  Anyone who can access Docker can access any of the images and manage any of the containers.  Further, anyone who can access Docker can pretty trivially give themselves root permissions over the entire host.  Consider the security implications of this when setting up Docker on a multi-user server; for instance, it might be appropriate to require `sudo` permission to do it.

Comment: `Why is the mirror public to everyone?` What mirror? What do you mean by "why"? Because someone made it that way.

Comment: I'm very sorry. Not mirror, but image. I mean: Isn't there no privacy in this way? And it's not safe, why is the image not private?

Comment: Docker generally requires root acces to run in the first place. So anyone who has root access to the machine has access to docker, including everything else on the machine really. Your docker images are no exception.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever has access to the docker socket, which is an interface to control the docker daemon (which is for example responsible for building a docker image), will see your images on the host machine. In general, users with root access have access to the docker socket and hence can see your images.

If you were the only root user on the machine, other users would not have access to the images in case that they were not in the docker group (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/).

But other than that I don't see a possibility on how to make your images "private" from other users controlling the docker socket.